# Optionally match within a regex group

Tags: regex

I am using regex to parse nginx logs.

One of the fields I'm creating is 'message'.  Sometimes this group will contain a JSON string.

How can I optionally match within my 'message' group to create a 'json' group?

Here's my current regex:

```
(?<time>\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \[(?<log_level>\w+)\] (?<pid>\d+).(?<tid>\d+): (?<message>.*)
```

Here's an example message:

```
2017/12/02 12:45:40 [debug] 29#29: *7895 [lua] auth_client.lua:41: {"applicationName":"nginx", "applicationFunction":"auth-client" ,"logLevel": "DEBUG", "clientId":"xyz","requestId":"72e03798e9826f2c4b076e3779903edf","message":"Checking client credentials"}
```

With my current regex I get a field like:

```
message: *7895 [lua] auth_client.lua:41: {"applicationName":"nginx-auth-filter", "applicationFunction":"auth-client" ,"logLevel": "DEBUG", "clientId":"ifly","requestId":"72e03798e9826f2c4b076e3779903edf","message":"Checking client credentials"}
```

What I would like is:

```
message: *7895 [lua] auth_client.lua:41: {"applicationName":"nginx-auth-filter", "applicationFunction":"auth-client" ,"logLevel": "DEBUG", "clientId":"ifly","requestId":"72e03798e9826f2c4b076e3779903edf","message":"Checking client credentials"}
json: {"applicationName":"nginx-auth-filter", "applicationFunction":"auth-client" ,"logLevel": "DEBUG", "clientId":"ifly","requestId":"72e03798e9826f2c4b076e3779903edf","message":"Checking client credentials"}
```

However, sometimes message doesn't contain json so the group should be optional.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with an optional group for json string:

```
(?<time>\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) \[(?<log_level>\w+)\] (?<pid>\d+).(?<tid>\d+): (?<message>[^{]*(?<json>\{.*\})?.*)
```

This is assuming json text starts with first `{` and ends with last `}` in the message group.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Dilxt/2)

Comment: This almost works but sometimes I do not end the message with }.  In this case the match doesn't work.

For example, I may have a message ending like:

}, client: 172.19.0.123, server: nginx.services.xxx.com, request: "POST /event/member HTTP/1.1", host: "api.xxx.com"

Comment: Also try my updated regex. If it doesn't work then edit the question with new sample data and also show expected matches.